# Pandas - Calculating daily differences relative to earliest value

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

This is probably pretty easy, but for some reason I am finding it quite difficult to complete. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. I have some time series data consisting of 5-minute intervals each day, ala:

```
Date                   Values
2012-12-05 09:30:00    5
2012-12-05 09:35:00    7
2012-12-05 09:40:00    3
2012-12-05 09:45:00    2
2012-12-05 09:50:00    15
2012-12-06 09:30:00    4
2012-12-06 09:35:00    3
2012-12-06 09:40:00    8
2012-12-06 09:45:00    1
```

I would like to calculate the differences relative to the first value of the day (which in this case always will be the 9:30 value), ie. end up with this DataFrame:

```
Date                   Values
2012-12-05 09:30:00    0
2012-12-05 09:35:00    2
2012-12-05 09:40:00    -2
2012-12-05 09:45:00    -3
2012-12-05 09:50:00    10
2012-12-06 09:30:00    0
2012-12-06 09:35:00    -1
2012-12-06 09:40:00    4
2012-12-06 09:45:00    -3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need substract by `Series` created [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df.Values.groupby(df.Date.dt.day).transform('first'))
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    5
4    5
5    4
6    4
7    4
8    4
Name: Values, dtype: int64

df.Values = df.Values - df.Values.groupby(df.Date.dt.day).transform('first')

print (df)
                 Date  Values
0 2012-12-05 09:30:00       0
1 2012-12-05 09:35:00       2
2 2012-12-05 09:40:00      -2
3 2012-12-05 09:45:00      -3
4 2012-12-05 09:50:00      10
5 2012-12-06 09:30:00       0
6 2012-12-06 09:35:00      -1
7 2012-12-06 09:40:00       4
8 2012-12-06 09:45:00      -3
```

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted your suggestion slightly: 
    df.Values.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("D")).transform('first'))

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting:

```
df.Values - df.Values.iloc[0]
```

Comment: @jezrael I think the output is right, the above expression just needs to be assigned to `df.Values` and then `print(df)` yields the same output as the expected output given in the question.

Comment: There is problem you cannot substract by first values by all `Series` but first values of multiple days, so need `transform`

Comment: You're right. I used `pandas.read_clipboard()` to read the data which resulted in `pandas` using the date portion of the datetime string as a `str` index, so it turned out correctly by "accident". I suppose it would have been nice if @Myggen- specified what the types of his columns were.