# Pandas - calculate relative difference compared to a fixed item

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas beginner here, so apologies if the question seems noobish.
My data is for 4 quarters, and the sales value are for each salesperson for each quarter:

```
QTR Name    QTR_Sales   Sales_YTD   Rel_Diff
Q1  Anna    3002        3002        -171
Q2  Anna    3532        6534        -358
Q3  Anna    4487        11021       -506
Q4  Anna    3454        14475       259
Q1  Dave    3173        3173        0
Q2  Dave    3890        7063        0
Q3  Dave    4993        12056       0
Q4  Dave    3195        *15251*     0
Q1  Helen   2429        2429        -744
Q2  Helen   2235        4664        -1655
Q3  Helen   4615        9279        -378
Q4  Helen   3258        12537       63
Q1  Jim     3339        3339        166
Q2  Jim     3082        6421        -808
Q3  Jim     3156        9577        -1837
Q4  Jim     2382        11959       -813
```

I need to calculate the relative difference for each quarter (column `Rel_Diff`), between the "winner" (highest sales for the whole year, which is Dave) and everyone else. Everyone will be referenced, on a quarterly base, to Dave.

I did this in Excel, by finding the "winner" and storing it it cell `I1`...

```
=INDEX(Name;MATCH(MAX(Sales_YTD);Sales_YTD;0))
```

...and then referencing everything to the "winner":

```
=QTR_Sales-INDEX(QTR_Sales;MATCH(QTR&$I$1;QTR&Name;0))
```

(I won't even try to put everything into a single formula :))

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104449/pandas-calculating-daily-differences-relative-to-earliest-value) shows hot to do something almost similar, but does not have the quarterly requirement, and the reference value is always the first in the data frame, which is not the case in my task.

How can I do this using `pandas` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can identify the winner by grouping by the `Name`s, and summing `QTR_Sales` for each group:

```
winner = df.groupby(['Name'])['QTR_Sales'].sum().argmax()
# Dave
```

Alternatively, the winner's Name could be found by finding the row with the
maximum value of `Sales_YTD`:

```
df.loc[df['Sales_YTD'].argmax(), 'Name']
# Dave
```

Next, we can select the sub-DataFrame with rows corresponding to the winner:

```
df_winner = df.loc[df['Name']==winner, ['QTR', 'QTR_Sales']]
#   QTR  QTR_Sales
# 4  Q1       3173
# 5  Q2       3890
# 6  Q3       4993
# 7  Q4       3195
```

Now merge this sub-DataFrame with `df`, by merging on the `QTR` column only.
This is perhaps the line where most of the magic happens, since now each row contains both the original `QTR_Sales` and the winner's `QTR_Sales` (the values in the `QTR_Sales_max` column):

```
df = pd.merge(df, df_winner, on=['QTR'], suffixes=['', '_max'])
#      Name QTR  QTR_Sales  Rel_Diff Sales_YTD  QTR_Sales_max
# 0    Anna  Q1       3002      -171      3002           3173
# 1    Dave  Q1       3173         0      3173           3173
# 2   Helen  Q1       2429      -744      2429           3173
# 3     Jim  Q1       3339       166      3339           3173
# 4    Anna  Q2       3532      -358      6534           3890
# 5    Dave  Q2       3890         0      7063           3890
# 6   Helen  Q2       2235     -1655      4664           3890
# 7     Jim  Q2       3082      -808      6421           3890
# 8    Anna  Q3       4487      -506     11021           4993
# 9    Dave  Q3       4993         0     12056           4993
# 10  Helen  Q3       4615      -378      9279           4993
# 11    Jim  Q3       3156     -1837      9577           4993
# 12   Anna  Q4       3454       259     14475           3195
# 13   Dave  Q4       3195         0   *15251*           3195
# 14  Helen  Q4       3258        63     12537           3195
# 15    Jim  Q4       2382      -813     11959           3195
```

Computing `Rel_Diff` is now easy:

```
df['Rel_Diff'] = df['QTR_Sales'] - df['QTR_Sales_max']
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Anna', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Helen', 'Helen', 'Helen', 'Helen', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim'], 'QTR': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], 'QTR_Sales': [3002, 3532, 4487, 3454, 3173, 3890, 4993, 3195, 2429, 2235, 4615, 3258, 3339, 3082, 3156, 2382], 'Rel_Diff': [-171, -358, -506, 259, 0, 0, 0, 0, -744, -1655, -378, 63, 166, -808, -1837, -813], 'Sales_YTD': [3002, 6534, 11021, 14475, 3173, 7063, 12056, 15251, 2429, 4664, 9279, 12537, 3339, 6421, 9577, 11959]})

winner = df.groupby(['Name'])['QTR_Sales'].sum().argmax()
df_winner = df.loc[df['Name']==winner, ['QTR', 'QTR_Sales']]
df = pd.merge(df, df_winner, on=['QTR'], suffixes=['', '_max'])

df['Rel_Diff'] = df['QTR_Sales'] - df['QTR_Sales_max']
df = df.drop(['QTR_Sales_max'], axis=1)
```

yields

```
     Name QTR  QTR_Sales  Rel_Diff Sales_YTD
0    Anna  Q1       3002      -171      3002
1    Dave  Q1       3173         0      3173
2   Helen  Q1       2429      -744      2429
3     Jim  Q1       3339       166      3339
4    Anna  Q2       3532      -358      6534
5    Dave  Q2       3890         0      7063
6   Helen  Q2       2235     -1655      4664
7     Jim  Q2       3082      -808      6421
8    Anna  Q3       4487      -506     11021
9    Dave  Q3       4993         0     12056
10  Helen  Q3       4615      -378      9279
11    Jim  Q3       3156     -1837      9577
12   Anna  Q4       3454       259     14475
13   Dave  Q4       3195         0   *15251*
14  Helen  Q4       3258        63     12537
15    Jim  Q4       2382      -813     11959
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge a subset of rows belonging to "winner" and calculate "Rel_Diff2", using `DataFrame.eval()` function:

```
In [133]: (df.merge(df.loc[df.Name.eq(df.loc[df.Sales_YTD.idxmax(), 'Name']), ['QTR', 'QTR_Sales']],
     ...:           on='QTR',
     ...:           suffixes=['','2'])
     ...:    .eval("Rel_Diff2 = QTR_Sales - QTR_Sales2", inplace=False)
     ...:    .drop('QTR_Sales2', 1)
     ...: )
Out[133]:
   QTR   Name  QTR_Sales  Sales_YTD  Rel_Diff  Rel_Diff2
0   Q1   Anna       3002       3002      -171       -171
1   Q1   Dave       3173       3173         0          0
2   Q1  Helen       2429       2429      -744       -744
3   Q1    Jim       3339       3339       166        166
4   Q2   Anna       3532       6534      -358       -358
5   Q2   Dave       3890       7063         0          0
6   Q2  Helen       2235       4664     -1655      -1655
7   Q2    Jim       3082       6421      -808       -808
8   Q3   Anna       4487      11021      -506       -506
9   Q3   Dave       4993      12056         0          0
10  Q3  Helen       4615       9279      -378       -378
11  Q3    Jim       3156       9577     -1837      -1837
12  Q4   Anna       3454      14475       259        259
13  Q4   Dave       3195      15251         0          0
14  Q4  Helen       3258      12537        63         63
15  Q4    Jim       2382      11959      -813       -813
```