# Compute time differences in Pandas dataframe with respect to first value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a question that looks somewhat similar to [this one][1], however I don't know how to modify the answer given there to fit my problem.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date                   user
2012-12-05 09:30:00    0
2012-12-05 09:35:00    1
2012-12-05 09:40:00    2
2012-12-05 09:45:00    3
2012-12-05 09:50:00    4
2012-12-06 09:30:00    5
2012-12-06 09:35:00    6
2012-12-06 09:40:00    7
2012-12-06 09:45:00    8
```

and I want to compute the relative time differences between users 1, 2, 3... and user 0. This value should be added in a third column (preferably in seconds). So in this example, the result should be:

```
Date                   user     diff
2012-12-05 09:30:00    0        0
2012-12-05 09:35:00    1        300
2012-12-05 09:40:00    2        600
2012-12-05 09:45:00    3        900
2012-12-05 09:50:00    4        1200
2012-12-06 09:30:00    5        1500
2012-12-06 09:35:00    6        1800
2012-12-06 09:40:00    7        2100
2012-12-06 09:45:00    8        2400
```

I am looking at the answer provided but I don't think I can use `group_by` here. I am a bit stuck.
[1]: [Pandas - Calculating daily differences relative to earliest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104449/pandas-calculating-daily-differences-relative-to-earliest-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can [`subtract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) the first value and get the [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['diff'] = df['Date'].sub(df['Date'].iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
                 Date  user     diff
0 2012-12-05 09:30:00     0      0.0
1 2012-12-05 09:35:00     1    300.0
2 2012-12-05 09:40:00     2    600.0
3 2012-12-05 09:45:00     3    900.0
4 2012-12-05 09:50:00     4   1200.0
5 2012-12-06 09:30:00     5  86400.0
6 2012-12-06 09:35:00     6  86700.0
7 2012-12-06 09:40:00     7  87000.0
8 2012-12-06 09:45:00     8  87300.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract minimal value and convert timedeltas to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['diff'] = df.Date.sub(df.Date.min()).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
                 Date  user     diff
0 2012-12-05 09:30:00     0      0.0
1 2012-12-05 09:35:00     1    300.0
2 2012-12-05 09:40:00     2    600.0
3 2012-12-05 09:45:00     3    900.0
4 2012-12-05 09:50:00     4   1200.0
5 2012-12-06 09:30:00     5  86400.0
6 2012-12-06 09:35:00     6  86700.0
7 2012-12-06 09:40:00     7  87000.0
8 2012-12-06 09:45:00     8  87300.0
```

Comment: I tried this and it is giving me the following error: 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
    129 
    130         if mask.any():
--> 131             result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
    132 
    133     np.putmask(result, ~mask, np.nan)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Qubix - add `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` before my solution.